# Angulars ngModel is null when used in directives link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I am trying the following:

directive:

```
myApp.directive('financeInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            money: '='
        },


        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, ngModel) {
```

and am using in a form like so:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.money.notional" money="money" finance-input size="30" required
           placeholder="insert currency value"/>
```

controller:

```
.controller('addTradeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.master = new Money();
    $scope.money = new Money();
```

etc

moneyModel:

```
function Money() {
    this.notional = 0;
    this.maxPrecision = 10;
}
```

however in the link function ngModel is null, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth argument of the **link** function is either:

- The instance of the single controller listed in the **require** property.
- An array of all of the controller instances listed in the **require** property, if **require** is an array.

Remove the fourth argument called "ctrl" from your link function, making ngModel the fourth argument, and you should be good to go.

Comment: thanks but how can I also get the controller so I can do:  **ctrl.$parsers.push(function (inputValue) {**

Comment: can I do :  **link: function (scope, element, attrs,  [ctrl,ngModel]) {**

Comment: In this case, you just need `link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {`. The `ngModelCtrl` argument will be the ngModel controller you can use for $parsers.

Comment: Thanks this directive stuff needs To be easier in 2.0

Comment: I now get ngModel passed in and has its properties set, but I see that **ngModel.$validators** is undefined and I need to set them with a custom function